# Java Sever Sending List of Words Back to Client

Tags: java, sockets

Essentially I have a client that sends a list of words to a server. The server removes the duplicated words. I store the 'remmoved duplicate' words in a new set, but I can't send the new words from this data structure back to the client. The program appears to be stuck in this loop ' while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) ' from the server class and I cannot then write the new set of words back to the client. Can Anyone help me with this please?

Can anyone help me with this please

Here is the Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class Server {

    private static boolean isFinished;

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception

    {

        String clientSentence;

        String capitalizedSentence;

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

        Set<String> lines = new LinkedHashSet<String>(10000);

        while (true) {

        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase();

            lines.add(capitalizedSentence);


        }

        for (String string : lines) {
            outToClient.writeBytes(string);

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception

    {
        String sentence;
        String modiﬁedSentence;
        File myfile = new File("C:/Users/Tudor/Desktop/test.txt");

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        Set<String> lines = new LinkedHashSet<String>(10000);

        while ((sentence = inFromUser.readLine()) != null) {
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");

            modiﬁedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();

            lines.add(modiﬁedSentence);
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modiﬁedSentence);
        }

        // for (String string : lines) {
        // System.out.println(string);
        // }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At client side you are reading with `BufferedReader#readLine` which expect a `\n` to come.

But from server, you are sending `string`(`writeBytes(string)`) without `\n` so how `readLine` will read that string.

Append `\n` in `string` which you are sending to client.

The main problem is here:

At client side you are expecting to get data from server after sending each line to server

```
while ((sentence = inFromUser.readLine()) != null) {
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");

            modiﬁedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();// here you are expecting the answer from server but server is busy in listening more data 

            lines.add(modiﬁedSentence);
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modiﬁedSentence);
        }
```

Your server is still busy in listening data.

```
while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase();

            lines.add(capitalizedSentence);


        }
```

Do some changes in server side code like this

```
while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase();

           outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence+"\n");
          // imideately send data after converting it as client is expecting the data to receive and must append '\n'  


        }
```

One more solution is::

Change the client side code as shown below:

```
while ((sentence = inFromUser.readLine()) != null) {
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");

// modiﬁedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); Remove this line from here

//            lines.add(modiﬁedSentence);
//            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modiﬁedSentence);
        }
```

Make a while loop for reading data from server

```
while ((modiﬁedSentence = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {

       // make 'clientlines'  as a set at client side  and store all lines coming from server       
               clientlines.add(capitalizedSentence);


            }
```

**A tip**: If you are using `DataOutputStream` for writing then use `DataInputStream` for reading.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem as the loop still hangs. I've tried with '\n' and '\r' and '\r\n'

Comment: yes I've tested that, and it worked but on the server side I have a set where I add all the lines, and after that loop is executed, I want to send everything that is in the set to the client but it only works inside the while loop and not after

Comment: @user2219097 You don't need that `for` loop because you  already have sent the data to client in `while` loop. At client side.. make a `set` and store the incoming line from server  in that `set`.

Comment: I need to add to the set in a while loop because I am removing the duplicates, so I want to send back to the client, only the non-duplicate lines and therefore need to use a for loop to go through the set and then send the new lines

Comment: @user2219097 See the edit.. You can apply one solution at a time from above. Dont apply them together.

Comment: sorry, I should have stated that the server needs to do the work (removing the duplicates). The client side should only receive the final lines

Comment: @user2219097 That depends on you what you want to send.. I have given the order of sending and receiving of messages. Apply that order only. And don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: but its crucial that the server does the work, so re-ordering the client to do the work defeats the purpose of the program